# Use ember cli mock server as actual server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli  with Firebase for my data. I also have a simple server file I created with http-mock that handles some processes for Twilio. Is there a way to use that http-mock as an actual server on Heroku? I have found an embercli stack for heroku but I'm not sure how to make that use the server file I have:

https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how to do this as well.

Comment: You want to use the mock server as your api?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm using Firebase for all of my data, I just have a mock server file to run some background processes for Twilio. Actually I'll put that into my question.

Comment: There is no built in way to do this with ember-cli and it's not recommended, it's not meant to be a real server. You would need to set up a separate server to do this.

Comment: Thanks @jakecraige that's basically of what I have concluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that build pack just deploys your app's static files to Heroku.

The http-mock file you're working with within Ember CLI is a Node Express app. So, you'd need to host it on a server that can serve node apps somewhere.

In theory you could write a script that does that (deploys it separately) while keeping it within your main repo, but like others have said that's probably not a good idea.

In the future, though, you probably will be able to use http-mocks both for clicking around your app with `ember serve`, and for use in your tests.